# Element to save results with different length in R

Tags: r, agrep

I want to extract similar text strings using the agrep function and save them in a list or vector, but the result has different length (even replacement could has length zero),so I get an error.

How can I define a list or vector in order to save the results even if they have different length?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
x <- c("REF.E600J","SIN MODELO","REF.E705N","24-53793A-K","24-53646A-K","33-53633A-K",
   "REF.E522N","CON MODELO","VAR MODELO","REF.E610L")

similitud <- list()

for (i in c(1:length(x))) {
similitud[i] <- agrep(x[i],x[-i],max=3,value=T)
}
#Error and warning
Error in similitud[i] <- agrep(x[i], x[-i], max = 3, value = T) : 
replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In similitud[i] <- agrep(x[i], x[-i], max = 3, value = T) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In similitud[i] <- agrep(x[i], x[-i], max = 3, value = T) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In similitud[i] <- agrep(x[i], x[-i], max = 3, value = T) :
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lists, you use `[[` not `[` to assign/get a single element (`[` returns a sublist).

```
for (i in c(1:length(x))) {
  similitud[[i]] <- agrep(x[i],x[-i],max=3,value=T)
}
```

Just change your `similitud[i]` to a `similitud[[i]]`.